# space after punctuation in LyX-2.3.6.2 on Mac

Tags: lyx, mac

I've just updated to LyX-2.3.6.2 on a Mac M1 running Monterey 12.0.1, and LyX has begun doing something odd with spaces after periods and commas, not displaying them at all:

[image]

There actually is a space after the period here, you just can't see it. It seems to handle spaces differently after commas and periods than between words or other punctuation. No issues after colons, semicolons, or exclamation points. There are no issues in the output pdf document, but it's a bit unnerving when writing to see whether or not there is a space missing.

Any tips for fixing? I've tried rolling back to prior versions as far back as 2.3 (without deleting application support folders) to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5):

As the previous post suggests, changing the screen font in Lyx Preferences/Look & Feel/Screen Fonts/Roman solves the issue.

I think on macOS Monterey, there is a problem with the .AppleSystemUIFont, which was set automatically in LyX after upgrading to 2.3.6.2. I changed the font to Arial which solved the spacing and some other weird issues. (For example, in Math editor "" looked more like "|").

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I solved my problem as well. However, I have another trouble. Now I cannot insert figures into LYX document as I was doing before changing Windows to Mac. Is there any problem with the figure installation in your Mac? If yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and I searched your question.
I tried many ways, and I solved it by changing the font.
**Lyx--performances--screen font--roman**